# Select random column from table excluding duplicates from another table column

Tags: sql

I am working on a game and I struggle with the following query.

```
SELECT 
    formUtf8General
FROM
    lexeme
WHERE
    LENGTH(formUtf8General) = 5
        AND frequency > 0.95
        AND (SELECT 
               word
             FROM
               game
             WHERE
               word = formUtf8General) = 0
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

This query selects a random word from a table column with a length of 5 and with a frequency greater than 0.95. The problem is that these words that get selected, will be added to another column but my `SELECT` for a duplicate is not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: please tag your dataabase and provide some data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What exactly do you mean by excluding duplicates? It would also be very helpful if you expanded on the overall database structure, as @nbk alluded to.

Comment: Your condition `AND (SELECT word FROM game WHERE word = formUtf8General) = 0`... is odd. In what situation will that SELECT output a literal `0`? Instead `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT word FROM game WHERE word = formUtf8General)`.

Comment: You are missing sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You want to change
`SELECT word FROM game WHERE word = formUtf8General` 
to
`SELECT count(*) FROM game WHERE word = formUtf8General`

What you are currently checking is for a word that is actually equal to `0`